# Question mark in binded text in template

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

While implementing angular translate i ran into French translation words such as: 'Propriété Catégorie' appearing in the view as `Propri�t� Cat�gorie`.

Dont know what this means. Is it that the used font doesnt have this character implemented? I think not since writing the HTML name `&eacute;` parses nicely into an `é`.

Question: how to implement this correctly, whats the way to go? Dont feel like going with the HTML name cause then I have to implement the way I place the translation key in a different way so it renders HTML instead of just strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your File is saved as ISO-8859-1 or any other 1 byte char set.
You are trying to read the File as UTF-8.

The solution:
Set your encoding to ISO-8859-1.

Or: Save the file as UTF-8.

Comment: this led me in the right directions. file encoding in the IDE was incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Put `<meta charset="utf-8">` in your html HEAD-section.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="fr" data-ng-app>
    <head>
        ...

        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    ...
</html>
```

Comment: about `lang="fr"` > this could be every language, at least 4 for now.